# How to get Insert ID after inserting data to MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a Mysql data table with the following details:

```
ID (int format) [AUTO_INCREMENT] 
date (varchar) 
ip (varchar)
activate(varchar) 
cdkey(varchar)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
                With sqlCommand
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO software (`date`, `ip`, `activate`, `cdkey`) values (@date,@ip,@activate,@cdkey)"
                    .Connection = SQLConnection
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", Label1.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", TextBox2.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@activate", "Yes")
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cdkey", textbox4.Text)



                End With
                Try
                    SQLConnection.Open()
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    iReturn = True
                    MsgBox("Display Last Insert ID here")

                Catch ex As MySqlException
                    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                    iReturn = False
                Catch ex As Exception
                Finally
                    SQLConnection.Close()
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
        Return
    End Sub
```

it's working except I'm trying to get the id number from the database after this data is inserted. How do I do that?

Comment: Those questions are confusing and the answers aren't clear. This here is clear question and an an amazing answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change your query to

```
  .CommandText = "INSERT INTO software (`date`, `ip`, `activate`, `cdkey`) 
                  values (@date,@ip,@activate,@cdkey);
                  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"
```

Then instead of ExecuteNonQuery you call ExecuteScalar and get back the value from the LAST_INSERT_ID()

```
   Dim newID As Integer = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

Comment: I used two execuescalar , one to insdert and one for the query. Removing that fixed the issue. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: How can I mark this as answer?